# How to extract slope and intercept values for different groups from interact_plots in jtools when plotting linear fixed effects models

Tags: r, plot, lme4

I am trying to extract the slope and intercept for each of my groups from my linear mixed effects models. The model was constructed using lmer in the lme4 library, and I can view the results for each group using interact_plot from the jtools library. How do I get the slope and intercept for each of these lines?

I know that I can use the summary() or summ() to see the estimates for the fixed effects and the variances of the random effects but I cannot see the estimates of the random effects. Therefore, I cannot accurately calculate the slope and intercepts of the models.

```
>library(lme4)
> cond_waterxsilver <- lmer(LnAg ~ LnVolume + (LnVolume | FilterID) + SilverType + WaterType + SilverType*WaterType + SilverType*LnVolume +  WaterType*LnVolume, data=capwater_removed.data)


> library(jtools)
> interact_plot(cond_ranin_waterxsilver, pred = LnVolume, modx = WaterType, mod2 = SilverType)
```

I am just trying to get the slope and intercepts for the six lines from the model (two different WaterType and three different SilverType). Is there a tool within jtools or another package that can help me with extracting the slope and intercepts from my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer of this package!

A short note: this and the other function I'm going to mention have just been moved to a new package, called [`interactions`](https://github.com/jacob-long/interactions), which is in the process of being added to CRAN. Assuming you haven't updated to the newest version of `jtools` (2.0.0; just came out days ago), these functions are still available in the `jtools` package. If you do update to `jtools` 2.0.0, you'll need to follow [this link](https://github.com/jacob-long/interactions) for instructions on how to download `interactions` before it gets to CRAN.

There should be a simple answer to your question. The `sim_slopes` (short for "simple slopes") function should give you what you're looking for.

```r
sim_slopes(cond_ranin_waterxsilver, pred = LnVolume, modx = WaterType, mod2 = SilverType, cond.int = TRUE)
```

This will print out the conditional slopes and intercepts (the intercepts are only printed when `cond.int = TRUE`.

If you need to program with those values, you can save the `sim_slopes` object.

```r
ss <- sim_slopes(cond_ranin_waterxsilver, pred = LnVolume, modx = WaterType, mod2 = SilverType, cond.int = TRUE)

ss$slopes # Matrix of slopes with test statistics, etc.
ss$ints # Matrix of intercepts with test statistics, etc.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this question! jtools is a super useful package! I have one quick question about sim_slopes function. How are the slope and intercepts calculated and what is the pvalue testing? I am asking because in my model the slope estimates seem reasonable, however, the intercepts are all much smaller than the data would suggest. Any insight or literature on the subject would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!